# Copying files between 2 offline git repositories

Tags: git, gitlab

I need to copy a group of files in differents folders from a specific git repository into another git repository offline.
Any recommendations without getting into conflict

Comment: The question is not clear to me. How is that related to programming or git? Are those different checkouts of the same repository (i.e. have same origin)?

Answer (score 1):

If the original folder where you copied the files from didn’t change then just copy the files that you changed to the original source paste and merge them there.
Then do.

```
git add .
git commit -m “with remote changes”
git push -u
```

This should work without any issues.